# In the sentence 雑誌のほうは彼に渡してくれ, what does のほう mean?

Tags: usage

I found this sentence in an anki deck, which gives its translation as "Give him the magazine" or something to that effect. I understand the rest of the sentence but I'm not sure why it has ほう in it, especially since I've mostly seen that word in the "x より　y のほうが” construction.

Comment: So you encountered this sentence in isolation in a pre-made deck and have no further context?

Answer (score 5):

> 「雑誌{ざっし}**のほう**は彼{かれ}に渡{わた}してくれ。」

There are **two** possible interpretations or meanings for this sentence.  Which one is "correct" would entirely depend on the context.

**1**) There is one other item mentioned/discussed in the context besides the magazine and the speaker wants the listener to give/hand only the magazine (but not the other item) to Person X.

"Give (only) the magazine to him!"

**2)** There is only one item, the magazine, being discussed in the context.  Quite a few native speakers use 「～～の方{ほう}」 because it can make them sound more **indirect and thus politer** overall than saying 「雑誌は彼に渡してくれ。」, which can sound a little too direct and possibly curt to some Japanese-speakers.

> I've mostly seen that word in the "x より　y のほうが” construction.

Glad you mentioned it.  This is related to the first interpretation above.  You have two items at hand and you say one of them is more [adjective].  That is the one that is serving some kind of purpose for you.