# 〜ほうを as in 準備のほうを

Tags: particle-を, sentence-final-particles

彩音{あやね} was doing something and 砂子{すなこ} reminded her that she should prepare herself for something else, saying:

> 彩音さん 準備のほうを

She just answered

> は〜い

But I didn't understand that ほうを. Is it the same as ほうがいい？If not, and if there is a verb being omitted, what verb could be?

Comment: as you provided reply also...it seems that ほうをis used as ほうがいい. But i just want to point out one thing that young generation of japan while talking with each other they mostly do not complete the sentences. Its totally informal way of talking and its better to stay away from such sentence formation while learning language. That was best advice my 先生 given to me when I started learning japanese.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ほうがいい.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72755/in-the-sentence-%e9%9b%91%e8%aa%8c%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86%e3%81%af%e5%bd%bc%e3%81%ab%e6%b8%a1%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8c-what-does-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bb%e3%81%86-mean/72756#72756

Comment: @l'électeur it's perfectly related. It really helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of ほう is used to make the sentence sound euphemistic and/or courteous. According to 明鏡国語辞典第2版:

> #### 方
>
> ④ 物事をぼかしていったり遠回しにいったりする。多く、ぼかすことで慎み深い気持ちを表す。
> 「金融の方に勤めています」「お仕事の方は順調ですか」

So 準備のほうを is a milder/politer equivalent of 準備を, and the omitted verb is simply してください or しなさい. Maybe Sunako used ほう because she knew she was going to interrupt Ayane.

This type of ほう can be potentially added to many nouns to make a sentence euphemistic. Here are exaggerated examples (taken from [here](https://eagleeye-identity.com/%E3%80%8C%E3%80%9C%E3%81%AE%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%8E%E3%81%AB%E6%B3%A8%E6%84%8F%EF%BC%81/)):

> かつて大学のほうでは、経済学部のほうに在籍しておりまして、金融経済のほうを学んでおりました。学生時代にしていたスポーツのほうは、野球のほうをしておりまして、趣味のほうはと言いますと、音楽鑑賞のほうになります。家族のほうは姉と４人家族で、出身のほうは北海道のほうになります。
>
> ---
>
> 館内のほうでは、スリッパのほうの着用をお願いしております。お食事の際には前もってご案内のほうをさせていただきます。宿泊費のほうですが、割引券のほうをお持ちになっていますので、割引のほうをさせていただきます。ご説明のほうは以上になりますが、ご質問のほうはございますか。よろしければお部屋のほうにご案内のほうさせていただきます。

These illustrate how のほう can be potentially used in many places in a sentence, but they are almost jokes. You definitely should not overuse のほう like this.

Other (safe) examples include:

- お体のほうは大丈夫ですか。
- お会計のほうを(お願いします)。

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually fits perfectly with the context! I learned something new with you today. Thanks!